# WPF set visibility of item in listbox - code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, button, listbox

I have listBox (added in code behind) and i want to set visibility of last item when Items.Count > 4. I have list box full of buttons.

```
private void movingOfButtons(ListBox list, int index)
    {
        Control previousButton = (Control)list.Items.GetItemAt(list.Items.Count - 1);
        int itemCounts = ktery.Items.Count;

        indexButton = index;
        // create new buttons
        addNewButton("Sound");
        addNewButton("addSound");
        mainCycle(list);

        // this does not work - it show only messageBox
        if (itemCounts >= 4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + previousButton.Name);
            previousButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        (list).Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
```

This `previousButton.Visibility` does not work.

Where is error?

Comment: Try Visibility.Hidden

Comment: You have to click on Ok in order to proceed to next step once you call MessageBox.Show else UI Thread will wait and you will never set the visibility :) :)

Comment: @devhedgehog That's not solution... It does not work also when I delete that MessageBox. :) :)

Comment: It was worth a guess hehe. How can I know what you up to? You havent posted much about what exactly you are doing. Show us more code. Is previousButton null? Do you get any exceptions? Take a look at your output window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error:

I have to "refresh" items in listbox.. ;)

```
mainCycle(list);

previousButton = (Control)list.Items.GetItemAt(list.Items.Count - 1);

        if (itemCounts >= 4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + previousButton.Name);
            previousButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

Comment: And we all know what mainCycle is doing right? How is this question gonna help somebody who stumbles upon this thread with an similar visibility issue? Idk.. Glad you solved it anyways.

Comment: @devhedgehog I posted only important code. But ok:
addNewButton create new button with name, index, and this method put that button to global list..
mainCycle just put these buttons from list to listBox...

That's all... but I think that's not important. :)

Comment: So you reset your ListBox each time you add a button by doing something like this listBox.ItemsSource = myList? Thats bad. You lose SelectedItem you lose scroll position. Its like taking chair away from somebody whos about to take a seat lol. Thats mean. Have you ever though of using ObservableCollection?

Comment: No. I'm adding and deleting buttons normal through Add or RemoveAt and via indexes. List is there for another reason. But lol - tha's really offtopic. :) :)